# Issue when installing DiscordSharp NuGet Package

Tags: c#, json.net, package, installation, nuget

**I have resolved this issue, please see the answer I posted**

I am having an issue when I try to install DiscordSharp ([Github](https://github.com/Luigifan/DiscordSharp) | [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiscordSharp/0.4.3.3-alpha)) using the Package Manager Console.

When I use the install command as shown on the Discord Sharp NuGet page I get the following error (sorry about the formatting see my comment for a screenshot of the error):

```
PM> Install-Package DiscordSharp -Pre
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.0)'.
Install-Package : The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child     element 'developmentDependency' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'copyright, tags, description, frameworkAssemblies,
references, dependencies, releaseNotes, language, summary' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package DiscordSharp -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

This is the error I get in a new project before installing any other packages, and I get the same error after installing json.net before DiscordSharp.

If it helps I am using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

If there is anything I have missed in the post which is needed, please let me know. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Click here for the error as seen in Visual Studio for formatting purposes](http://i.imgur.com/gfrPaOx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: My version of NuGet was outdated as I was using Visual Studio 2012.

Updating to Visual Studio 2015 resolved this issue.